# Is my hard drive faulty?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I have a new laptop with both an SSD and an HDD. However, it seems like the HDD is faulty because content on it seems to skip. For example, I'd play a game on it and occasionally the game would freeze and have to catch up by running 3x faster. Or, my music would pause and then start playing again 5 seconds later.

SMART only shows a possible UltraDMA CRC error. I've read that this is due to a faulty cable. I hope this is the case, but if not, a new hard drive wouldn't be hard to get ahold of.

Any ideas? Is the cable bad, or is the hard disk bad? I'll run more diagnostics later.

Comment: What OS are you running? It might just be the power options spinning the HDD down (to save power), and when it needs to be accessed again, it has to spin up thus causing delays in whatever program needs that HDD data.

Comment: See if you can re-seat the drives open it up. Playing with the drives should not cause the warranty to go out. If you are worried about those kinds of things.

Comment: Have you tried a new cable?

Comment: I opened up my laptop and noticed (a while back) the cable looked a bit odd. It could very well be the cable, but I'm not sure where to buy one (I'll look around though. They shouldn't be too hard to find.) I'm running Windows 10 Pro, and in the power options I turned off the disk shutdown feature while plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to not be faulty as of this time. I have Intel Rapid Storage Technology installed and Link Power Management was enabled. I have since disabled it, and I also moved my music back to my HDD and I haven't had any problems with it having to catch up. Movies also seem to play smoothly without pause. I'll have to play a game now and find out for sure if it's fixed. It was very prominent in Shadow of Mordor.

Comment: It doesn't seem to freeze anymore after I turned off link power management.

Answer (score 0):

From what I heard, [SpinRite](https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) is a good HDD diagnostic and recovery tool.

You can also try diagnosing your hard drive by listening to it - if the sound goes sharp or you hear repeated ticks during the slowdowns, it might be related to skipping. Rotating the hard drive somewhat might be a temporary fix to the issue (I know it helped me in the past), but I wouldn't trust the drive to be reliable for much longer if it skips.

However, you might not have hdd issues entirely - freeze / speedup issues might be caused by the computer being slow or lagging for some reason. Music usually is small and cached in memory, so it shouldn't be skipping like that.

Comment: Running SpinRite on a SSD in the wrong mode isn't a great idea.

Comment: The problem is with my HDD, not SSD.

Comment: I have Intel Rapid Storage technology, and Link Power Management was enabled. I have disabled it now and I'll see if that was the culprit. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score -1):

Try using your OS' Task/Activity Monitor to determine what is consuming your resources, what resources are being utilized, and how much is being utilized (RAM, CPU or HDD). If this primarily happens while gaming, it could easily be your video card. Maybe see where your card stacks up in a comparison like the "Video Card Heiracrchy" lists found at the TomsHardware website. You could also try installing a program like FRAPS to get an idea of your actual performance.

Your laptop most likely does not have a cable connecting the HDD. The HDD is probably attached to a SATA connector mounted directly on the Motherboard. As @NetworkKingPin mentioned, you should be able to open the bottom of the case and reseat the HDD into the connector.

If you think there is still a problem with the HDD, there are quite a few diagnostic tools you can use. The most common tools are Parted/GParted on Unix-like systems, Chkdsk on Windows, and HDUtility on Mac. GParted can also be found on many "Boot CD" utilities such as Ultimate Boot Disk. There are also vendor specific tools from most major manufacturers ( http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/ , http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?DL , etc). Finally, I have heard many good things about HD Tune, but I have never used it myself.

Answer (score -1):

You should unplug your HDD and clean the dust on it (if there is any). Afterwards, you should plug it back on (maybe use a new cable) and install CrystalDisk tool - I used it many times and worked like a charm. When you handle your HDD mind the static electricity!

Comment: It's brand new, so there's no dust.